# JSON sorting large data sets

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

http://openlibrary.org/search.json?q=prolog

I have the above API which i am going to be implementing in a android application.

Is there a way to grab from the json on the fly. a specific field for instance:

if i search the above i would need the Author, Language, suggested_title and ISBN. for each result. (so in the above case there would be 100 results.)

which i the plan on storing in a array in the format of

Title|author|lang|ISBN

Comment: Check out jq: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ It's like sed for JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        URL testing = new URL("http://openlibrary.org/search.json?q=prolog");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(testing.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        String test = null;
        int i =1;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
                if (inputLine == "\"title_suggest\":")
                {
                    test = inputLine;
                }
        }
            in.close();
            System.out.println(test);

    }
}
```

appears to work

as i could then add test to array location [x][y]